# Чёрно белая картинка при добавлении фото в андроид студио

Tags: android

при добавлении картинки в андроид студио она становиться чёрно белой вообще не понимаю в чём проблема, сами фото в цвете и формат файла подходящий заранее спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: В приложении андроид студио можно добавить фото в ImageView но у меня при добавлении фото когда я нажимаю добавить фото выбрал его в папке и оно появилось на маленьком экране оно становится чёрно белого цвета и я не знаю что с этим делать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните свой вопрос. В идеале прикрепить код ImageView, сам файл картинки и скриншот вашей ошибки.